# Reaction in discord py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have 1 question. How can my bot(discord.py) delete reaction after user add it. That is, the user clicks on the reaction, a channel is create and then the reaction is remove. Help please

Comment: What have you tried? What documentation have you looked at?

Comment: I tried reaction.remove, message.remove_reaction. Read discord.py docs, but didn't find something, maybe because i didn't see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you try to remove a Reaction, you can use the `await remove_reaction(emoji, member)` function ([more here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.remove_reaction)) and to create a Channel you can use the `await create_text_channel(name, *, overwrites=None, category=None, reason=None, **options)` funktion ([more here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel)). To find out how to work with them, please [read the Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)